# HTML and CSS not working

Tags: html, css, web

I'm just trying to make my CSS work with my HTML code but it's not working for some reason. I think I did everything correctly...maybe its just my browser? I'm on a mac using TextWrangler, testing with Safari/Chrome. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <div id="heading" name="heading" title="topbar">
            <h2> Welcome to our website </h2>
        <style type="text/css">
            #bottom{
                width:70px
                color:green
                align-content:center


            }



        </style>
    </head>


    <body>


    <div id="bottom" name="bottombar" title="bottombar">
            <h2>Welcome to our website </h2>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `align-content` doesn't work unless the element also is `display:flex`

Comment: People, please stop posting random answer, until we know what the actual problem is!

Comment: I'm not too worried about that, because the basic ones such as color aren't working

Comment: @AnishSethi You need to explain what is wrong, or your question will be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put `<div>` in the head section, here is the modified code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style type="text/css">
            #bottom{
                width:70px;
                color:green;
                align-content:center;
            }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="heading" title="topbar">
        <h2>Welcome to our website</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom" title="bottombar">
        <h2>Welcome to our website</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You forgot the closing semi-colons in the css `;` and also forgot to close your divs, hope this helps.

Comment: @AnishSethi Instead of commenting “thanks”, _accept the answer_ by clicking the check mark next to the voting arrows.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things wrong:

- Your `head` should not contain `div` tags
- You forgot semicolons at the end of your CSS attributes
- `div` should be closed (`</div>`)

Answer (score -1):

Your divs are missing their closing tags i.e. `</div>`

I'm also not sure why you duplicate the div in the head. it should only be in the body.

Comment: Man I'm stupid... I just tried to put </div> tags in there though and the CSS still isnt working...